# Помогите разобраться, как реализовать передачу параметров в функцию

Tags: javascript

Есть задание:

> Наша функция partial позволяет фиксировать только первые аргументы. Усовершенствуй ее, чтобы зафиксировать можно было любые аргументы, пропущенные аргументы обозначаются с помощью undefined. Обрати внимание, что теперь мы переименовали ее в partialAny, чтобы не путать с предыдущей:

```
function test(a, b, c) { return 'a=' + a + ',b=' + b + ',c=' + c; }
var test1_3 = partialAny(test, 1, undefined, 3);
console.log(test1_3(5)); // a=1,b=5,c=3
```

Вот функция, которую надо усовершенствовать:

```
function partial(fn) {
    let args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return function() {
        return fn.apply(this, args.concat(
            Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)
        ));
    };
};
```

Не могу понять, как заменить `undefined` на аргументы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Главное отличие новой функции заключается в том, как передаются параметры в конечный вызов.

Если сейчас они просто добавляются в конец, то сейчас нужно, предварительно смержить два массива параметра.

Для этого можно написать функцию `merge`.

В качестве примера можно реализовать ее как функцию-генератор:

```
function* merge(first, second) {
  var j = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < first.length; i++) { // бежим по первому массиву
    yield(first[i] === undefined) ? second[j++]: first[i]; // если значение undefined - возвращаем значение из второй последовательности и увеличиваем счетчик иначе возвращаем элемент из первого массива
  }
  for (; j < second.length; j++) { // возвращаем оставшиеся элементы из второго массива 
    yield second[j];
  }
}
```

В результате выйдет массив, в котором вместо `undefined` элементов первого массива будут значения из второго.

Его-то и надо будет передать в качестве параметра вместо простой конкатенации: `args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0))`

Пример реализации:

```js
function* merge(first, second) {
  var j = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
    yield(first[i] === undefined) ? second[j++]: first[i];
  }
  for (; j < second.length; j++) {
    yield second[j];
  }
}

function partialAny(fn, ...boundedArgs) {
  return (...args) => fn(...merge(boundedArgs, args));
}

function test(a, b, c) {
  return 'a=' + a + ',b=' + b + ',c=' + c;
}
var test1_3 = partialAny(test, 1, undefined, 3);
console.log(test1_3(5)); // a=1,b=5,c=3
```

В примере использованы [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Rest_parameters), [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), [функция-генератор](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*), [стрелочная функция](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 1):

Я решил след. образом:

```
function test(a, b, c) { return 'a=' + a + ',b=' + b + ',c=' + c; }

function partialAny(fn) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    var unArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        if (args[i] === undefined) unArr.push(i);
    }
    return function() {
        var j = 0;
        var args1 = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
        if (unArr.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < unArr.length; i++) {
                args[unArr[i]] = args1[j];
                j++;
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < args1.length - unArr.length; i++) {
            args.push(args1[j]);
            j++;
        }
        return fn.apply(null,args);
    };
};

var test1_3 = partialAny(test, 1, undefined, 3);

console.log(test1_3(5)); // a=1,b=5,c=3
```

Answer (score -1):

Не понял, что значит зафиксировать, но я обычно так делал, если надо было тягать любое количество аргументов. И когда наследуешься от partial, создаешь хоть эни, хоть бэни и можешь в нее сколькоко угодно аргументов лепить. Надеюсь я правильно понял вопрос.

```
function partialAny(test, 1, undefined, 3) {
    partial.apply(this, arguments);
};
partialAny.prototype = Object.create(partial.prototype);
partialAny.prototype.constructor = partialAny;
```